# RSA Key to PKCS#8 format

Tags: php, openssl, phpseclib

OpenSSL PHP code doesn't generate encrypted private key in PKCS#8 format

```php
    $passphrase = 'Hello World';

    $config = array ("digest_alg" => "sha256","private_key_bits" => 2048,"private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA );

    // Create the private and public key
    $res = openssl_pkey_new ( $config );

    /* Extract the private key from $res to $privKey */
    openssl_pkey_export ( $res, $priv_key, $passphrase );

    /* Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey */
    $pub_key = openssl_pkey_get_details ( $res );
    $pub_key = $pub_key["key"];
    $pkey_pair = array ('priv_key' => $priv_key,'pub_key' => $pub_key );

    /* Print it */
    var_dump($pkey_pair);
```

But PhpSeclib can:

```php
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);

extract($rsa->createKey());

echo $privatekey;
```

Now, is it possible to convert Private Key generated by openssl_pkey_new() to PKCS#8 using phpseclib.

I am not using phpseclib for signing and encryption because it is much slower as compared to php openssl functions. My client expects encrypted private key to be in PKCS#8 format.

Comment: Can you provide the result of `echo $privatekey;`?

Answer (score 1):

phpseclib should use OpenSSL if it's available (and the library and header versions don't mismatch; you should be on the latest version 0.3.10 since the matching requirements were slightly relaxed).

That said, you can convert RSA keys thusly:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//$rsa->setPassword('password'); 
$rsa->loadKey('...');

//$rsa->setPassword(); // clear the password if there was one
$privatekey = $rsa->getPrivateKey();
$publickey = $rsa->getPublicKey();
?>
```

By default getPrivateKey() returns a PKCS1 formatted private key. You can make it return keys in other formats by doing `$rsa->getPrivateKey(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PUTTY);`